# Why does Ruby treat variables and numbers differently for exponential equations?

Tags: ruby, math

When performing exponential calculations using a negative number as the base, inconsistent results are returned when using the raw value as opposed to a variable containing the value.

In IRB:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > -4.5 ** 0.5
 => -2.1213203435596424 
1.9.3p194 :002 > foo = -4.5
 => -4.5 
1.9.3p194 :003 > foo ** 0.5
 => (1.2989340843532398e-16+2.1213203435596424i) 
1.9.3p194 :004 > (-4.5) ** 0.5
 => (1.2989340843532398e-16+2.1213203435596424i)
```

What gives? Obviously the compiler is interpreting `-4.5 ** 0.5` as `-(4.5 ** 0.5)`, but why the different behavior when using a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's taking the first line as

```
-(4.5 ** 0.5)
```

which gives the negative square root of 4.5.
The second equation is equivalent to

```
(-4.5) ** 0.5
```

hence the complex answer.

Comment: I understand *what* it's doing, but *why?*

Comment: Can't find the actual core doc. This is from the Pragmatic Programmer's Guide: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4

Comment: As to the logic of having exponentiation before negation, I would say that negation is considered multiplication (by -1) and thus occurs after exponentiation.

Answer (score 3):

Because of operator precedence. Exponentiation `**` has the highest precidense. So you first raise a positive number to `0.5` and then negate it instead of what you expect. In the second case however, foo is already `-4.5` so negation takes precedence.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is not about precedence but about why `foo` that is once assigned `-4.5` cannot be decomposed into `-` and `4.5`, then the answer is too obvious. This is a very basic feature that is common to all language like systems, including all programming languages and all natural languages, as well as mathematic notations. Once some object `x` is evaluated/calculated, then it is a single thing. You cannot  go back to reinterpret it as multiple parts. All a language can do (be it a natural or programming) is, take `x` as a single object, and further concatenate it with other parts to calculate a larger meaning. There is no going back and decomposing something that has once been evaluated/calculated.

In natural language, this is called *constituency*. If a sequence of words `foo bar baz` is interpreted as `[foo bar] baz`, then there is no going back and interpreting it as `foo [bar baz]` at the same time.

In mathematics, sometimes the calculated value of `(foo bar) baz` may equal to `foo (bar baz)`, but that is only by applying a special property called *associativity*, and even though the value might become the same, they mean different things. And furthermore, associativity does not hold in general.

Answer (score 0):

`**` Has an higher operator precedence than `-`.  Here is an example with operators you may be more familiar with.

```
1 + 2 * 3  => 7

x = 1 + 2  => 3

x * 3      => 9
```